# Why does the highlightBlock(text) method of QT class QSyntaxHighlighter process one line of text each time?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

Recently I've been working on a PyQt regex tester, I need to highlight the matched result.

Here is my code:

```
def highlightBlock(self, text):
    index = 0
    length = 0
    for item in self.highlight_data:
        index = text.indexOf(item, index + length)
        length = len(item)
        self.setFormat(index, length, self.matched_format)
```

the self.highlight_data is a list which stores the matched data, and the method iterate the text to find them and highlight them. But when the matched data include the '\n'(multiple lines), the result won't be highlighted correctly.

When I debugged the code, I found the highlightBlock(text) method will be called several times if the text include multiple lines. Each time the parameter text is one line of the data.

Then I changed my code to:

```
def highlightBlock(self, text):
    index = 0
    length = 0
    for item in self.highlight_data:
        if item.count('\n') != 0:
            itemList = item.split('\n')
            for part in itemList:
                index = text.indexOf(part, index + length)
                if index == -1:
                    index = 0
                else:
                    length = len(part)
                    self.setFormat(index, length, self.matched_format)
        else:
            index = text.indexOf(item, index + length)
            length = len(item)
            self.setFormat(index, length, self.matched_format)
```

This will solve the problem.

Here is my question: why does the highlightBlock(text) method process one line each time? Why not just transferring the whole text(including '\n') one time instead of one line for several times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the clue is in the name: "highlightBlock". It is called whenever *blocks* of text change within the document.

To quote from the Qt docs for [QTextEdit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#details):

> QTextEdit works on paragraphs and characters. A paragraph is a
>   formatted string which is word-wrapped to fit into the width of the
>   widget. By default when reading plain text, one newline signifies a
>   paragraph. A document consists of zero or more paragraphs. The words
>   in the paragraph are aligned in accordance with the paragraph's
>   alignment. Paragraphs are separated by hard line breaks.

So, since QTextEdit works on paragraphs/blocks, it is only natural that QSyntaxHighlighter should do likewise.